# Using jquery widget variables in draggable events

Tags: jquery, events, draggable

I want to build a horizontal scroller which can be dragged to a specific width. The width is set by the widget options. I realized however that I do not know how to use variables that I declared in the _created-function, in the draggable events.

Here is the (now working) code:

```
$.widget( "my.scroller", {
    options: {
        rangemin: 0,
        rangemax: 1000
    },

    _create: function() {
        var scrollerrange = (this.options.rangemax - this.options.rangemin)

        this.element.draggable({
            axis: "x",

            drag: function(event, ui){
                var this.left = ui.position.left;

                // here I want to replace 700 with 'var scrollerrange'
                // and it works
                if(this.left > 0) this.left = 0;
                if(this.left < -scrollerrange) this.left = -scrollerrange;

                ui.position.left = this.left;
            },

        })
    },
});
```

This is my first attempt at a jquery widget and I wonder if this is the right approach. I tried several things but nothing worked. I also tried extending my widget from draggable but eventually I came to the same dead end.

**EDIT:** It was actually just a typo in the code and it now works...

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Ahh noo. No that I've slightly rewritten the code for this post I realized it was just a typo.. and I wasted several hours with this. Thanks anyway for bringing me on the right track :)